# RAM Supported by Samsung SENS R530

Tags: memory

What is the maxmium RAM supported by Samsung SENS R530 Laptop?

The Current Configuration is as follows:

- OS: Win7 Ultimate 32 bit
- System Model: R530
- Processor: Pentium(R) Dual-core CPU T4300 @2.10GHz (2 CPUs) ~2.1GHZ
- Memory: 2048MB RAM

Comment: 4GB? [Its spec sheet](http://www.samsung.com/us/computer/laptops/NP-R530-JA02US-features) does say it anyway (if that's the right one).

Answer (score 2):

While i'm growing less fond of it, [SIW](http://www.gtopala.com/siw-download.html) should tell you - the portable version is only downloadable if you don't have adblocking on.

Hardware - memory - maximum memory capacity should tell you what you need

Answer (score 0):

I've always found the [Crucial Memory Advisor](http://www.crucial.com) to be an excellent tool to tell you exactly what you can expect to fit in a machine.

For the R530 it shows 8GB as the maximum you can fit. http://www.crucial.com/uk/store/listparts.aspx?model=R530&Cat=RAM

This is simply by selecting your model on their list, they also have an actual [system scanner](http://www.crucial.com/systemscanner) that can get a more precise match on your machine.